# how to save number as 0001 or 0006 in php, mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql

i am fetching database value of a column as 0005 , then i am adding 1 to it and save it in the database with a char ABHI  but  in the database its saved as ABHI6 not ABHI0006. how to do it??

here is the php script

```
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['name']);
$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['id_last']);
$id2=+$id;
$sql="INSERT INTO file (name, unique_id )
VALUES ('$name','$name$id2')";
```

Comment: what is the datatype of that column in DB

Comment: varchar @Manadh ..........................

Comment: i need to increase that value by 1 first @DavidKmenta

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked... try to use str_pad function http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php and you can increment number for example this way `$id++`

Comment: Where are you incrementing by 1? You're just doing `+$id`, which converts `$id` to a number.

Comment: And you are doing the increment in PHP ? something as `0005+1` if so then in an example file do it and see what it returns.

Comment: Did you mean to write `$id2 = 1 + $id`?

Comment: meaningless in any use case, when zero is the first digit of a number, there is no point in showing it. zero is only significant when it is to the right of a digit

Comment: Just store the number. Don't confuse/conflate issues of data storage with those of data retrieval and display.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use padding for the string

```
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['name']);
$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['id_last']);
$id2 = "$name".str_pad(++$id, 4, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
$sql="INSERT INTO file (name, unique_id )
VALUES ('$name','$id2')";
```

See refrence [here](http://php.net/str_pad)

Comment: What is `=+` supposed to do?

Comment: It will append the name i.e. "ABHI"

Comment: You'll get the name twice, since he's inserting `'$name$id2'` in the SQL.

Comment: its saving as 0006 but not increasing the value by 1

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
$id = "ABHI1";
$IncrementID =  substr($id, -1) +1;
echo substr_replace($id,$IncrementID,-1);
```

Out put

```
ABHI2
```